# Old data in cell.textLabel when 'reloadData' after change in sqlite db

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, uitableview

I've a UITableView and sqlite db.
The textLabel and detailTextLabel and image come from db.
When I delete a row and then add a new one (add to 'array' and then 'reloadData') the 'textLabel' get old data.
What I see in the log is the correct data should be in the label but old data is in label.
I checked the data come from db and all is correct.

My code:

ADD GROUP:

```
NSString *userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"userID"]];
            NSString *groupName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
            NSString *mobile = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userPhoneNumber"];

            NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [parameters setObject:userID forKey:@"userID"];
            [parameters setObject:groupName forKey:@"groupName"];
            [parameters setObject:mobile forKey:@"mobile"];

            @try {
                NSString *responseXML = HTTP_POST(WEB_SERVICES_URL, @"addGroup", parameters);
                NSLog(@"\nResponse XML (addGroup):\n%@\n", responseXML);

                Group *aGroup = [[Group alloc] init];
                aGroup.groupID = [[IDAN_XML_Parser sharedInstance] getResponseFor:@"answer" inXML:responseXML].integerValue;
                aGroup.visible = kTrue;
                aGroup.manager = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"userID"];
                aGroup.name = groupName;
                aGroup.time = [[MobileControlHandler sharedInstance] getFormattedDate];

                [[SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase] addGroup:aGroup];
                [CoreDataHandler getGroups];
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                listOfGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                listOfGroups = [[SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase] getAllGroups];
                [tableGroup reloadData];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"addGroup Exception: %@", exception.reason);
            }
            @finally {}
```

DELETE ROW:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        indicator.center = self.view.center;
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        @try {
            Group *aGroup = listOfGroups[indexPath.row];
            NSMutableArray *allMembersInGroup = [[SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase] getAllMembersInGroupID:aGroup.groupID];
            NSString *membersIDs = @"";
            printf("allMembersInGroup.count: %i\n", allMembersInGroup.count);

            if (allMembersInGroup.count > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < allMembersInGroup.count; i++) {
                    GroupMember *aGroupMember = allMembersInGroup[i];
                    membersIDs = [membersIDs stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,", aGroupMember.memberID]];
                }
                membersIDs = [membersIDs substringToIndex:membersIDs.length - 1];

                [CoreDataHandler deleteGroupMemberID:membersIDs inGroupID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", aGroup.groupID]];
            }

            [CoreDataHandler getGroups];
            [tableView endUpdates];
            [tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
            listOfGroups = [[SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase] getAllGroups];
            [tableView reloadData];
            [tableView setNeedsLayout];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [indicator stopAnimating];
            indicator.hidden = YES;
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:%i, Exception: %@", indexPath.row, exception.reason);
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [indicator stopAnimating];
            indicator.hidden = YES;
        }
        @finally {}
    }
}
```

And this is how I configure the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:31];
    UILabel *detailTextLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:32];


    Group *newGroup = listOfGroups[indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = darkGrayColor();

    textLabel.text = newGroup.name;
    NSLog(@"newGroup.name: %@, textLabel.text: %@", newGroup.name, textLabel.text);
    textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontNameBold size:kFontSizeBig];
    textLabel.tag = kTagLabelGroupName;
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:kFontSize];
    detailTextLabel.text = newGroup.time;
    detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    detailTextLabel.tag = kTagLabelGroupDate;
    detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    //    cell.imageView.image = self.imageGroup.image;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [CoreDataHandler decodeImageFromBase64:newGroup.picture];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image = [CoreDataHandler imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });


    /* UIImageView *imageGroupManager = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 25, 25)];
     imageGroupManager.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
     imageGroupManager.tag = kTagPictureStar;

     if (newGroup.manager == [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"userID"]) {
     [cell insertSubview:imageGroupManager aboveSubview:cell.imageView];
     } */

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I changed the self made textLabel to cell.textLabel and all went well, but the problem is I cannot change the text direction, probably change it to customised cell should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing UITableViewCell solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try by the change:

Original code:

```
[CoreDataHandler getGroups];
[tableView endUpdates];
[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
listOfGroups = [[SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase] getAllGroups];
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView setNeedsLayout];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
[indicator stopAnimating];
indicator.hidden = YES;
```

changed code:

```
[CoreDataHandler getGroups];
listOfGroups = [[SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase] getAllGroups];
[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
[tableView endUpdates];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
[indicator stopAnimating];
indicator.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: 2013-11-20 18:06:31.371 MobileControl[3276:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1330

Comment: 2013-11-20 18:06:31.374 MobileControl[3276:60b] commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:0, Exception: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).